# Why apex classes should declare a sharing model if dml or soql is used?

Tags: apex, pmd

I have installed Apex PMD in my visual studio code for the static analysis of my code.

I have a global class and inside it, I have written some DML/SOQL query. The static analyzer shows a warning

> Apex classes should declare a sharing model if DML or SOQL is used
>   (rule: Security-ApexSharingViolations)

Why apex classes should declare a sharing model if DML or SOQL is used?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As explained in the documentation:

> Apex generally runs in system context; that is, the current user's
>   permissions, field-level security, and **sharing rules** **aren’t taken into
>   account during code execution**.
>   Because these rules aren't enforced, developers who use Apex must take care that they don't inadvertently expose sensitive data that would normally be hidden from users by user permissions, field-level security, or organization-wide defaults. They should be particularly careful with Web services, which can be restricted by permissions, but execute in system context once they are initiated.
>
> Most of the time, system context provides the correct behavior for
>   system-level operations such as triggers and Web services that need
>   access to all data in an organization. However, you can also specify
>   that particular Apex classes should enforce the sharing rules that
>   apply to the current user. (For more information on sharing rules, see
>   the Salesforce online help.)

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_security_sharing_rules.htm)